# JsonConvert.SerializeObject is escaping "@" in my object

Tags: c#, json

I'm having an issue with `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` when I try to serialize my object with:

```
var statementOfAccount = new
                {
                    main = new 
                    {
                        @xm = "https://api-path.com",
                        RESTHeader = new 
                        {
                            Responsibility = "Responsibility ",
                            RespApplication = "AR",
                            NLSLanguage = "AMERICAN"
                        }
                    }
                };
```

And giving me:

```
{
  "main": {
    "xm": "https://api-path.com",
    "RESTHeader": {
      "Responsibility": "Responsibility",
      "RespApplication": "AR",
      "NLSLanguage": "AMERICAN"
    }
  }
}
```

So basically it's removing the @ from @xm and please note that I can't change the name of the property so I need a solution that will serialize it as is.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with an anonymous object - you have to create a class and use the `JsonProperty` attribute I think.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim

Comment: @Jodrell Thank you. That's the link I was trying to find. :)

Comment: The `@` indicates a verbatim identifier

Comment: You'll need to create the type with a valid c# names, then either, write your own serializer or annotate the type so that your serializer of choice uses the name you want. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-customize-properties?pivots=dotnet-6-0

Comment: As an alternative to creating a class (if this is a one-off), serializing a dictionary is another possibility, with recent advances in syntax for initializers (`new Dictionary<string, object> { ["@xm"] = "https://api-path.com", ["RestHeader"] = new { Responsibility = ... }`). Note that dictionaries and anonymous objects can be mixed this way. Of course a class may be preferable anyway for long-term maintainability.

Comment: As mentioned, the `@` isn't doing what you think it does. It's not part of the name at all, it's just an escape character. You can't have `@` in a field name, so you'll need to use `JsonProperty`.

Answer (score 1):

one way would be to create a custom class instead of using an anonymous

```
public class Custom
{
....
[JsonProperty["@xm"]
 public string @xm {get; set;}
....
}
```

since your anonymous object properties are known and can't cause any property overlaping, another way is to replace a  json string  after serialization

```
json=json.Replace("xm:","@xm:");
```

Comment: The "replace after the fact" strategy is both inefficient and risky, as there's nothing to prevent the string `xm:` from appearing in the output as something other than a property name. Best not go down that path to begin with.

Comment: @JeroenMostert see my updated answer. And it is radiculous to talk about performance when you have 100 byte string

Comment: The problem is not with the properties themselves being known, but that (in real code) you'd expect things like `Responsibility = responsibilityFromUserInput` rather than a fixed string as per the question. If you really knew not only all the properties but also their values at compile time an even simpler way is to just paste in the JSON string verbatim rather than messing around with serialization at all.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I am assuming that OP  put a real code.   And I am not offering it as a generic soluition for any cases. Why you don't post  your solution? It is always easy to critisize everybody when you  can not offer anyting.

Comment: Or perhaps the attribute should be [JsonPropertyName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonpropertynameattribute?view=net-6.00)

Comment: My comment is not personal criticism, or at least not intended to be so, but a remark to point out that this technique has the potential to fail in general, which I think would be valuable to readers, especially since answers on SO are read by many people, not just the OP. I'll leave it at that.

Comment: @Jodrell or perhaps the attribute should be JsonProperty.  Pls give a chance to OP owner to try it and to let me know if there is a problem.

Comment: @JeroenMostert It is not a generic question. There is code that is not working properly and OP asking how to fix it. Why you don't  give a chance to OP owner to try it and to let ME know if there is a problem still. I will then offer something else.

Comment: I would upvote if you hadn't suggested the post replace.

Comment: @Jodrell Thank you, but I don't need to be upvoted, since I have a plenty of score already. I just try to help people. This is why I became upset, since in many cases OP doesn't  appreciate any help, but I have to argue with another users for nothing.

Comment: @Serge, happens so often.

Comment: @Serge, I really appreciate your help,thank you, but the thing is that I can't upvote any solution since I have less than 15 reputations :(

Answer (score 1):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-customize-properties?pivots=dotnet-6-0

this solved my problem to use JsonPropertyName but with JsonSerializer.Serialize instead of JsonConvert.SerializeObject so the problem was me using an anonymous object as most of you suggested but using JsonPropertyName only worked with JsonSerializer.Serialize, it didn't work with JsonConvert.SerializeObject

solution:

```
  public class Main
    {
           [JsonPropertyName("@xm")]
            public string @xm { get; set; }
            public RESTHeader RESTHeader { get; set; }
        }

    public class RESTHeader
    {
        public string Responsibility { get; set; }
        public string RespApplication { get; set; }
        public string NLSLanguage { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public Main main { get; set; }
    }


   var statementOfAccount = new Root
                {
                    main = new Main
                    {
                        @xm = "https://api-path",
                        RESTHeader = new RESTHeader
                        {
                            Responsibility = "Responsibility ",
                            RespApplication = "AR",
                            NLSLanguage = "AMERICAN"
                        }
                    }

                };

var json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(statementOfAccount);
```

Comment: The confusion is that `JsonProperty` is for `JSON.Net` serializer and `JsonPropertyName` is for the `System.Text.Json` serializer.